# Seeking open source implementation just like ArcGIS Desktop Identity function?

Tags: software-recommendations, algorithm, open-source-gis, web-service, identity

I tried to identity thousands of points with millions polygon. ArcInfo works well but I have to get the result from Web Services.

I tried to implement the algorithm (Point in polygon) by myself,it doesn't work efficiently.

Is there any faster algorithm or implementation to solve this?